# SAT-3CNF - Clique

Tags: np-complete, reductions

Could someone show me ( or give me a valuable hint) how to reduce k-Clique problem to SAT-3CNF problem ? I am able to prove reduction from SAT-3CNF to k-Clique, but in the opposite direction it's hard.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, but as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.  We expect you to make a significant effort before asking and to show us what you've tried.

Comment: but the most difficult step is to come up with an idea. Without this I can't start solving this...

Comment: The purpose of exercises is to diagnose your understanding, give you practice, and help you figure out where you need to study or practice more.  If you don't have any ideas at all for how you might get started, then I suggest you go back and do more self-study of the topic of reductions (there's lots of material available), and work on some easier practice problems first.  If you can't show anything you've tried or any ideas of your own, you're probably not ready to ask here on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your hint: write down a Boolean formula $\varphi$ (it doesn't have to be in 3CNF) that expresses the condition that your graph contains a $k$-clique.